# How to add several unpivot() functions in the same select statement ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my example,

```
WITH TABLE1 (ID,COL1,COL2,SUBCOL1,SUBCOL2) 
as (select 1, 'm1',null,'s1',null from dual
    union all 
    select 2, null ,'m2', null,'s2' from dual
)
select * from TABLE1;
```

From above table1 I want to create a view as follows,

```
ID      | COLTYPE |     col    |    SUBCOLTYPE  |  subcol
-------------------------------------------------------------
1          COL1        m1            SUBCOL1         s1 
2          COL2        m2            SUBCOL2         s2
```

what I did was I merged `COL1` , `COL2` in to `COL` and `SUBCOL1`, `SUBCOL2` in to `SUBCOL`. Can I achieve this by using `UNPIVOT()` function.

my imaginary query is as follows,

```
select * from table1 
unpivot(COL for COLTYPE in (COL1,COL2))      --- FIRST MERGE
unpivot(SUBCOL FOR SUBCOLTYPE IN (SUBCOL1,SUBCOL2))  ---SECOND MERGE
;
```

Each first and second merge lines are working individually when comment other one. But They are not working same time.  How to add several `unpivot()` function in the same select statement. Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to the original question**

Why do you want to use unpivot? I ask because you are not transposing columns into rows. Is it guaranteed that all the columns you want to merge are NULL except one of them? If yes you could use the [coalesce](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/COALESCE.html#GUID-3F9007A7-C0CA-4707-9CBA-1DBF2CDE0C87) function.

Source data:

```
        ID COL1     COL2     SUBCOL1  SUBCOL2
---------- -------- -------- -------- --------
         1 m1                s1
         2          m2                s2
```

Example:

```
WITH TABLE1 (ID,COL1,COL2,SUBCOL1,SUBCOL2) 
as (select 1, 'm1',null,'s1',null from dual
    union all 
    select 2, null ,'m2', null,'s2' from dual
)
select id,
       coalesce(col1,col2) as col,
       coalesce(subcol1, subcol2) as subcol 
from TABLE1;
```

Result:

```
        ID COL      SUBCOL
---------- -------- --------
         1 m1       s1
         2 m2       s2
```

**Answer to the updated question**

After you edited your question, this syntax is probably what you are looking for:

```
WITH TABLE1 (ID,COL1,COL2,SUBCOL1,SUBCOL2) 
as (select 1, 'm1',null,'s1',null from dual
    union all 
    select 2, null ,'m2', null,'s2' from dual
)
select id, coltype, col, subcoltype, subcol from TABLE1
UNPIVOT ((col, subcol) FOR (coltype, subcoltype) IN ((col1, subcol1) AS ('col1', 'subcol1'), (col2, subcol2) AS ('col2', 'subcol2')));
```

Result:

```
        ID COLTYPE          COL      SUBCOLTYPE                   SUBCOL
---------- ---------------- -------- ---------------------------- --------
         1 col1             m1       subcol1                      s1
         2 col2             m2       subcol2                      s2
```

Comment: thanks, your awnser is correct for my example. but my question is still there. yes you are right. I modified my question. I want to transpose two set of columns. so I can't do it using single unpivot() function.